# mySQL query doesn't work as it is supposed to

Tags: mysql

I need to get all the comments from a database where the author of the blog is a certain number. Except my SQL query doesn't use the right author id.

This is my query:

```
SELECT em_comments.*, em_users.nickname
FROM em_comments
INNER JOIN em_posts ON em_posts.id = em_comments.post
INNER JOIN em_users ON em_users.id = em_comments.author
WHERE em_posts.author = 1
ORDER BY date DESC
```

As you can see, It is supposed to only get the comments of the posts where the author of the posts is 1. The results I get back is 4 comments, yet there are 6 comments in total that should be recovered from the database.

I know that the problem is somewhere with

```
WHERE em_posts.author = 1
```

Because some how this query only returns the comments of which the comments author is 1. But it should return all comments for all posts where the post author is 1.

Anyone has any ideas on how I can get this fixed?

Thanks in Advance,
Mark

EDIT:

The comments table structure + data

```
id | post | author | date                 | content
6    7      1       2012-05-10 12:30:25     Dat weet hij zelf ook xD
5    6      1       2012-05-10 12:30:12     yup
1    1      1       2012-05-09 13:39:34     Whoop Whoop! Eerste comment test! xD
2    1      1       2012-05-10 12:27:49     Nice. tweede comment werkt nu ook
3    1      1       2012-05-10 12:29:45     Nice. tweede comment werkt nu ook 
4    1      1       2012-05-10 12:30:00     Nice. tweede comment werkt nu ook
```

The posts table structure + data

```
id | author | date                | content                                                 | title    
7    1        2012-05-09 19:42:33   Mark is nog topper geworden vandaag. xD                   Mark is nog cooler
6    1        2012-05-09 19:30:27   Mark is top!                                              Mark
1    1        2012-05-07 19:21:03   lol test met &#039;quotes&#039; en &quot;dubbele q...     Whoop Whoop!
```

The users table structure + data

```
id | nickname
1    Mark
2    Kevin
```

Comment: 99.99% of the time MySQL is right and doing exactly what it should do. If I were you, I'd double and triple check that you aren't doing something stupid before claiming that MySQL is giving you the wrong results. Show us your table structure, your data, and give a proof of why you think six rows is the correct result.

Comment: It looks right to me. You're definitely querying WHERE em_posts.author=1, and not the em_comments.author. How do you know for sure you should have six instead of four results?

Comment: please update the relationship between the tables

Comment: You have not written the name of table em_users in scond line after FROM

Comment: Could you provide an example on [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: See my updated post for the tables structures and data

Comment: Author id 0 (of comments 2 and 3) doesn't exist in the users table.

Comment: Oops my bad. In the database they are 1. Sorry. I copied them wrong

Comment: With the corrected data, your query returns 6 records as desired.  [See it on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab3c7/1).

Comment: What? Strange. How can it work with you guys, but not with me...

Comment: Most likely reason is that the contents of your database (or the query you are running) don't exactly match what is in your question/in the sqlfiddle; the `0`s you thought you had copied incorrectly are likely candidates - I'd check again the contents of your `comments` table.

Comment: Looks like it had something to do witch my cookies. I delete my browsers cookies and sessions and then it worked. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1):

Inner joins exclude rows that have NULL values in the ON clauses. Check the values of the rows in the columns to see if any are coming up NULL.

Comment: I checked for NULL values, but every column in the database is filled